# __thiscall with __stdcall behaviour

Tags: c++, calling-convention

I am reverse engineering an old C++ code and I found something which I cannot understand how can be accomplisehd from a normal C++ code. The function signature, from the DLL, is a mangled name which can be recovered to `public: void __thiscall MyClass::MyClass(int)`.

From the MS documentation, `__thiscall` functions have the `this` member, for non static methods, passed using the ECX register. Well, this particulcar function makes the correct use of the ECX register passing but also, from the disassembled code, the first parameter is not the `int` argument, but also a pointer to the object.

This is what I can see from the DLL public names:

```
void __thiscall MyClass::MyClass(int);  
main() {  
  MyClass *pmc;  
  MyClass *pmc2;  
  pmc = new MyClass(pmc2,0);  
}
```

So, on this case, the constructor (and other methods also), seems to be defined as:

```
void __thiscall MyClass:MyClass(MyClass *arg0, int arg1)
```

Any ideas how something like this can be accomplished?

Comment: How something like what can be accomplished?

Comment: Ditto to the previous question -- why is any of this surprising?  You've happened upon a constructor that, as expected, observes the __thiscall calling convention.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking, is "if the this pointer is already getting passed via ECX, then why does it also appear to be getting pushed onto the stack?"  My question back to that is "How did you accomplish the reverse name mangling in the first place?" (e.g. show us the mangled name). And  "how did you disassemble the function to believe that the calling patter nwas also passing 'this' on the stack?" (Show us the disassembly).

Comment: Using dumpbin, the DLL shows, among other exported entriees:

Comment: Using dumpbin, the DLL shows, among other exported entriees: `70   3B 0000552A ??GCSLOleDateTimeSpan@@QBE?AV0@ABV0@@Z`. Using unmangle: `public: class CSLOleDateTimeSpan __thiscall CSLOleDateTimeSpan::operator-(class CSLOleDateTimeSpan const &)const`. The calling code for this method is: `lea     eax, [ebp+arg0] ; push    eax ; lea     eax, [ebp+work]; push    eax; mov     esi, ecx; call    CSLOleDateTimeSpan::operator-(CSLOleDateTimeSpan const &)`. Note that there are three parameters pushed into the stack, among with the this pointer passed into ECX.

Comment: The disassembled code for the method is:`                     push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
fldz                                        ; Load +0.0
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
mov     eax, ecx
mov     ecx, [ebp+arg0]
and     [ecx+CSLOleDateTimeSpan.CSLOleDateTime.off_0008_DateTimeStatus_], 0 ; Logical AND
fstp    [ecx+CSLOleDateTimeSpan.CSLOleDateTime.off_0000_DATE_] ; Store Real and Pop
mov     edx, [eax+CSLOleDateTimeSpan.CSLOleDateTime.off_0008_DateTimeStatus_]
push    2
pop     edi`

Comment: What makes you think the parameter is a pointer to the same instance and not a different instance of the same class - which would be pretty normal for `operator -`.

Comment: I am sure the pointer is to a different instance, which makes the implementation of this operator impossible. From this code, the methods is implemented with three arguments, which does not make sense. The first argument is from ECX (this ptr), the second argument, which I think should be the second value, seems to be a pointer to a result instance. The third parameter in fact is the second argument. Something like "c=a+b", where all thre  arguments are passed to this method.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.
When a function or method returns a non basic type, the memory allocation is made on the caller side and the function (or method) simply receives the pointer.

For example

```
ClassB __thiscall functionName(param1)
```

will be compiled to

```
ClassB var1;
ClassB * __thiscall functionName(&var1, param1)
```

at assembly level the return type address will be pushed last into the stack. If a functionName is a class method, ECX will point to the class instance. Otherwise, ECX will be ignored.